# Is Ember really a single page app?

Tags: ember.js, single-page-application

I have been studying [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com) for about a week now and all examples I studied were single page apps. I have been told to work on a project which expands more than 30 pages and I have no idea what the directory structure would be and if Ember is the best tool as I have never seen an application that links to other pages in the project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, ember is a single page application, since you only go to one page, it loads the app then you don't need to fetch anymore pages from the server the ember app handles everything. For bigger apps like the one you're suggesting, you'd put each object type (models, controllers, routes, templates, views, etc...) into their own directory for organization.

Comment: thanks for the answer .so what you are saying is i have COntroller folder and i dump all the controllers related to a page into that folder ? and how about if i logged into an app and want to fire up a page on successful login? how does ember handle that ?

Comment: You'd just put all of your controllers of your app in the controllers folder. I would move away from the term page, since really there are no pages just states of the application (based on what route you're on).

Comment: Check out https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-tools should help creating ember apps

Answer (score 0):

I quite like to use Ember JS for SPA due to it's flexibility but when it comes to browser support, then I've no choice but to go for Knockout JS for implementing a SPA!

They are both great for SPA, Ember has lot more to offer, but for those that must still support IE7 then the best choice would be Knockout JS...

Hope it helps :)