# Ember is only for one page website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am really interested in `Js MVC framework` like Ember but in many places.

I read that ember is used for one page web application.

I have some confusions.

1. Can I use ember for large scale application having lots of pages?
2. If I can't then which MVC framework is best for large applications.

Suggest your ideas...

Comment: See the answer of Srihari, I only like to add: technically it _is_ a single application page that is served to the client. Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No JS MVC Framework would be written aiming at one page web application. As per Ember's own website, http://emberjs.com/#routing-example

> Ember.js makes it downright simple to create sophisticated, multi-page JavaScript applications with great URL support, in a fraction of the code you'd write in other frameworks.

So to answer your questions:

1. Yes.
2. All JS MVC frameworks listed at http://todomvc.com/

Answer (score 3):

One can use **Ember.js** with or without the `Ember.Router`. If the application doesn't need to change the browser's address bar, the following will setup a basic, one "page" Ember installation.

Given the following code:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    // Append application to a selector
    rootElement: '#ApplicationView'
});

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    // Set the default location
    location: 'none'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    // Set the default path to home
    this.resource('home', { path: '/' });
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    init: function() {
        console.log("Application route initialized");
    }
});
```

The following template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</script>
```

Will be appended into our HTML page:

```
<div id="ApplicationView"></div>
```

Comment: +1 This is completely true, you can let the server handle the 'routing actions'.

Answer (score 1):

The One page web application term technically does not apply to Ember. It relies on the URLs being the fundamental driving force behind rendering or display of views.

For instance if you had a webpage located at /home and another webpage located at /search - you would accordingly wire up Ember's route to set up the controllers, routes and views accordingly. Each template can be organized and named according to Ember's naming conventions

if you want the page /home in your app, you will have the following (adapted from http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/):
a home template,
a HomeRoute,
a HomeController,
and a HomeView.

Similar question here - [Is Ember really a single page app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645109/is-ember-really-a-single-page-app?rq=1)